# Transition links works in jsfiddle but not on my browser

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

The orange links of my code transition perfectly here --> http://jsfiddle.net/v8X9H/134/
Yet, on my browser nothing. Thinking it had something to do with the onload I switched

```
$(function() {
```

**TO**

```
$(window).load(function() {
```

Still nothing. What am I not seeing?

Comment: What do you mean by "on my browser"? What are you viewing the fiddle in?

Comment: you load the jquery library on your site?

Comment: Also note, you fiddle is using an auto `$.load()` wrapper for that jQuery.

Comment: Google chrome, by loading I meant on a servver @JaredFarrish

Comment: So when you bring it up in Chrome, the "orange links" transition correctly? Which ones? The one link below the text inputs? We have to be able to recreate your problem, and as of yet, I'm unsure what it is.

Comment: Yes, I know @JaredFarrish. Which is why I figured $(window).load(function() { would work

Comment: On the Jsfiddle link I provided --> http://jsfiddle.net/v8X9H/134/  The links that says "You have an account..." only work on jsfiddle. It does not work on chrome

Comment: You still haven't explained what a "transitions perfectly" does. What is the problem, plainly, and how can I reproduce? jsFiddle is not a browser; also note, you have `Normalize CSS` checked on the left in the fiddle. Are you using that normalization CSS script on your site?

Comment: You see how when you click the link it fades out and another box fades in? That is not happening when I load the files onto my ftp. The normalized css is fine. All the code needed to reproduce is sectioned off in jsfiddle. I'm assuming its a javascript code issue just need some fresh eyes to spot it for me @JaredFarrish

Comment: @noviceintraining - Are you saying that when deployed to your server the (orange) hyperlinks don't work at all, i.e., when you click them nothing happens? Or do you get an "imperfect" transition where something happens but not the right thing? _"just need some fresh eyes to spot it for me"_ - But you've provided a _working_ example, so...

Comment: Try the Chrome Console, check for errors.

Comment: Yes to the first one. My terminology isn't that great I know, thanks for understanding what I was trying to say @nnnnnn

Comment: It's possible you're setting a load handler during the load handler itself; in that case, the latter will never fire. Check that; you can `console.log('my load handler fired');` at the top of you *own* handler to check it ran, just be sure to have the console open.

Comment: Yea just tried that, still nothing @JaredFarrish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For code transition outside of jsfiddle, did you put the JS code inside a ready/onload function?

i.e.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // JS Code goes here
});
```